# How many clocks does sequential division take?

Tags: math, division, cpu-architecture

Here is the question:

[image]

and according to the solution key, the correct answer is `e`.

I know that when we divide 2n-bit number by n-bit number to produce n-bit quotient and n-bit remainder, we need `(n+1)×2` clocks.

Why do we need 20 clocks, 20-bit registers, and 20-bit ALU to ***correctly*** perform this sequential division?

Correctly may mean: with no overflow.

Comment: Just to verify... Are we talking here about HW design? If not, then we need more information on what the specific system can do with one clock cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In sequential division, you will have to be able to place the divisor on the left-hand side of the dividend for the add/subtract operation.

You might want to think of the situation where the divisor is 1. Then it is clear that you will have to shift it up to the most significant 1 in the dividend. As the simple logic does not know anything about the number or position of bits in each number, the only safe thing is to shift the divisor far left.

This is why you need the double number of bits in the registers and the ALU.